# Why is my cross-validated search generating nan scores for large datasets?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I am trying to use a cross-validated search to find the best bandwidth to use as my kernel density estimate for a random set of points.

If I run the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingRandomSearchCV

mu = 0
sigma = 1
num_markers = int(1e6)
marker_positions = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, num_markers)

bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-1, 0, 20)
grid = HalvingRandomSearchCV(KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-3), \
                    {'bandwidth': bandwidths}, \
                    n_jobs = -1, \
                    cv = 3, \
                    refit = False, \
                    aggressive_elimination = True, \
                    verbose = 4)
grid.fit(marker_positions[:, None])
```

I get the following error (note that this is not the full error):

```
UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.
```

Note that using `GridSearchCV` instead of `HalvingRandomSearchCV`also gives the same error.

However, if I change the number of data points to 10^5 instead of 10^6, i.e. I set

```
num_markers = int(1e5)
```

then the code works fine.

If I run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingRandomSearchCV

mu = 0
sigma = 1
num_markers = int(1e5)
marker_positions = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, num_markers)

bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-1, 0, 20)
grid = HalvingRandomSearchCV(KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-3), \
                    {'bandwidth': bandwidths}, \
                    n_jobs = -1, \
                    cv = 3, \
                    refit = False, \
                    aggressive_elimination = True, \
                    verbose = 4)
grid.fit(marker_positions[:, None])

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth = grid.best_params_['bandwidth'], kernel='gaussian')
kde.fit(marker_positions[:, None])

x_min = -3
x_max = 3
nx = 1001
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, nx)
log_density = kde.score_samples(x[:, None])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, np.exp(-x**2/2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi), label = 'Exact')
ax.plot(x, np.exp(log_density), label = 'Estimate')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.legend()
plt.savefig('probability_density_estimate.png')
plt.show()
```

then this gives the following graph:
[image]
Do you know why the code is setting scores to Nan? Why does it only do this when I have a large data set?